# Stack when use POST with Twitter API, JSON.parse did not work correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class TwittersController < ApplicationController

  def create_twitter_cart

twitter_connector(
    'twitter_api_key',
    'twitter_api_secret',
    'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=currss%20bip&display_coordinates=false',
    'post'
)


redirect_to action: "show", controller: 'lips', id: session[:lip_id]


  end




  def open_tweet_lip

consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(
    Rails.application.secrets.twitter_api_key,
    Rails.application.secrets.twitter_api_secret,
    {:site => 'https://api.twitter.com'}
)

token = OAuth::ConsumerToken.new(consumer, 'twitter_api_key' , 'twitter_api_secret')
######################################
### Here bad code
######################################
#JSON.parse(token.request(:post,  'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=a2a2sssssscurrss%20bip&display_coordinates=false').body)

abort

redirect_to action: "show", controller: 'lips', id: session[:lip_id]
  end



end
```

I am stack with that,

if i abort like this, i have 403 code error and status tweet is duplicate

```
JSON.parse(token.request(:post,      'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=a2a2sssssscurrss%20bip&display_coordinates=false').body)
```

abort

but if i am using that everything all right

abort
in web console

```
JSON.parse(token.request(:post,  'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=a2a2sssssscurrss%20bip&display_coordinates=false').body)
```

I cant understand what the reason of this anomaly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is most likely showing "tweet is duplicate" because your test code is updating with the same status every time. Try updating to do something like this:

```
JSON.parse(token.request(:post,  "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=a2a2sssssscurrss%20bip%20#{rand.to_s}&display_coordinates=false").body)
```

At least this will give you a random string on the end of your status which Twitter will hopefully ignore as not being a repeat of the previous status.

Comment: @DimKamovski i'm pleased it worked. Please consider marking this answer Accepted.